# How do I set the -windowtitle parameter when generating javadoc in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc

I want to add the -windowtitle parameter when generating the javadoc.

Answer (score 3):

- Select your project in the **Projects** tab, right click and select **Properties** from the menu.
- Select **Build > Documenting** from the list of **Categories**.
- Enter the title in the **Browser Window Title** field and click **OK**. (Note that you can further customize the Javadoc output in the **Additional Javadoc Options** field.)

[image: windowTitle1]

- Select your project in the **Projects** tab, right click and select **Generate Javadoc** from the menu.
- The title you provided will appear on the browser tab. It will be prefixed by the name of the project but I don't know how to prevent that.

[image: windowTitle2]

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly for me although, just to note, I didn't get the prefix, just the name that I typed in the Browser Window Title box. I'm using NB 8.2 in windows 10 and Chrome browser.

These are the settings:

[image: netbeans browser window title settings]